# Why my component is rendering 4x times even with useCallback and useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm a beginner in React and I'm trying to fetch data using Axios.

This fetching is being controlled by useState (loading, errors, getting data) and useEffect/useCallback.

My code has a console.log("hey") just to show me when the component is being rendered.

```
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DriversList from "./components/DriversList";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const apiGetDataHandler = useCallback(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    axios
      .get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/drivers.json?limit=25")
      .then((response) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setDrivers(response.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    apiGetDataHandler();
  }, [apiGetDataHandler]);

  let content = <DriversList drivers={drivers} />;
  console.log("hey");

  if (error) {
    content = <p>{error}</p>;
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    content = <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section>{content}</section>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of react are you using, and do you use `<StrictMode>`?

Comment: @NicholasTower React 18.2.0 and yes, I'm using `<StrictMode>` in the `index.js`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming react 18 and `<StrictMode>`, here's the 4 renders:

The component mounts, and that's **render #1**

After the first render, the effect runs and you call `setIsLoading(true)` and `setError(null)`. Since loading changed from false to true, this results in **render #2**. Also, the `axios.get` is kicked off.

Because of [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state), react simulates unmounting/remounting the component, and runs your effect again. The calls to `setIsLoading` and `setError` won't actually cause another render, because the new values are the same as the old values, but the effect does kick off an additional call to `axios.get`

Some time later, one of the `axios.get`s finishes. You call `setIsLoading(false)` and `setDrivers(response.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers)`. Both of these result in changes, which are batched up into a single **render #3**.

Some time later, the second `axios.get` finishes. You call `setIsLoading(false)` and `setDrivers(response.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers)`. The loading part doesn't change anything, but the drivers does change, resulting in **render #4**.

---

You can eliminate 1 render by having `isLoading` start off as true. That way, when you call `setIsLoading(true)` right after mount, nothing changes.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

You can eliminate another render by having your useEffect return a teardown function which stops the fetch when the component unmounts. You could either cancel the fetch entirely via an [axios abort controller](https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation), or just set a variable reminding you to not set the state when it finishes. Also, if you move the function into the effect, you won't need to use `useCallback`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let cancelled = false;

  setIsLoading(true);
  setError(null);

  axios
    .get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/drivers.json?limit=25")
    .then((response) => {
      if (cancelled) {
        return;
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
      setDrivers(response.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (cancelled) {
        return;
      }
      setError(error.message);
    });

  return () => {
    cancelled = true;
  } 
}, []);
```